# How can I define a self closing XML element in a DTD file?

Tags: xml, validation, dtd

The element that I want to define:

```
<testing-element code="Input"/>
```

The code I've put in my DTD file:

```
<!ELEMENT testing-element ()>
<!ATTLIST testing-element code CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

The problem is, that you are currently not allowed to leave the brackets from the !ELEMENT tag empty

Comment: Why not to use XML Schema instead of DTD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the element like this:

```
<!ELEMENT testing-element EMPTY>
```

An empty pair of brackets like in your example isn't valid content model declaration syntax.

This will allow you to specify the element either in XML-style empty element syntax

```
<testing-element/>
```

or with start- and end-element tags:

```
<testing-element></testing-element>
```

There's no way to *require* empty-element syntax (owing to XML's SGML heritage).

Technically, you can also use empty end-element syntax on any element that happens to accept empty content eg. has a content model with all elements optional:

```
<ELEMENT e (f?)>
```

or that isn't declared at all when using lax validation.